# Как обработать правильно JSON ответ в Java применяя Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Например выполняется  GET запрос и приходит ответ в виде JSON:

```
{
      "name": "John",
      "age": 25,
      "roles": {
        "isAdmin": false,
        "isEditor": true
      }
    }
```

Но по такой же ссылке иногда приходит ответ с дополнительными атрибутами , например ID:

```
  {
              "ID":12** 
              "name": "John",
              "age": 25,
              "roles": {
                "isAdmin": false,
                "isEditor": true
              }
            }
```

**ВОПРОС:**

Как в таком случае написать POJO объект (класс) , чтобы он подходил под разное кол.во атрибутов? Или если мне нужен только определенный атрибут, то достаточно в POJO объект включить переменную с этим названием?  По технологии описанном тут
 https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, достаточно объявлять только необходимые поля. Если каких-то полей не будет, то можете сделать их `@Nullable` и они будут `null`, если в JSON их нет

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что одним из условий должно быть точное совпадение название переменных и атрибутов в JSON?

Comment: В общем случае - да. Однако можно в аннотациях к полям указывать и другие имена. Например чтобы в Java было `userName`, а в JSON `user_name`

Comment: А не додскажешь почему не принимает URL  в  библиотеке Jackson?   
         URL url = new URL("https://someURL");

            
         CityList citylist = mapper.readValue(url, CityList.class);  Ругается  , смотри на скриншоте

Comment: Обычно либа делает что-то одно. Либо запросы в сеть, либо парсит JSON.

Comment: Уважаемый Юрий, я в этом деле новичок.  Моя цель- это как-то обработать (запарсить) JSON в объект Java, чтобы потом сравнить данные полученные из JSON с данными из БД. На основе этой информации отправить обратно в виде JSON данные из базы.

Comment: Сложно сказать как это на голой Java сделать. Обычно берут либу типа `OkHttp`, но я затрудняюсь сказать как её не через систему сборки типа `gradle` подключить. Попробуйте тут посмотреть варианты без сторонних либ. Вроде бы будут работать, если Java больше 10 версии. https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/